# mysql query returning more than one value - should return one

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have a website where visitors can create "battles" and upload videos to compete in these battles.

The following mySQL query is trying to retrieve details of every "battle" in a database.

The problem I have is that if a "battle creator" has uploaded two "videos" to the same battle, a duplicate battle prints out.

How can I make the query only print out one value for each battle, even if the videos table has two entries under the same battle_id?

Thanks!

```
SELECT * from Battles, Player, Video 
WHERE (Battles.battle_creator = Player.player_id 
AND Battles.battle_id = Video.battle_id 
AND Video.player_id = Battles.battle_creator) 
ORDER BY Battles.battle_date DESC;
```

Comment: Did you tried... `LIMIT 1` at the end ?

Comment: Hi - I want to retrieve every battle in the database, so I don't want to limit it to just one battle in this case. The problem is when I echo out the list of battles, a duplicate battle appears with a different video made by the same "battle creator"

Comment: You're using *inner join*. Do you really need all the fields from all the tables as you're using `select * from...`?

Comment: More information is needed as to what is being displayed.  If you want to show every battle once, what is supposed to happen if there is more than one video?  Why is the video information being included?  Do you display a link to each video?  If there is more than one video, what is your business rule?  Display the newest one?  Display the first one?

Comment: I think you've searching `DISTINCT` / `DISTINCTROW`, probably in a sub-query
OFF: you should really use joins

Comment: Scott - I'm selecting from every table because the other tables have information I want to echo out that's relevant to the battle. For example, a URL and username. My battles table only has a reference to player_id etc.

Comment: I simply want to print a list of every unique battle, with the image thumbnail to be relevant to the battle. The problem is when more than one video is uploaded to the same battle, by the same creator. It duplicates the listing. the final part of my query means that that doesn't happen for every video uploaded to the battle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get the information you're asking for from a single query once multiple videos have been assigned to a battle by a single user.

The best way to get all the data for the battle is to separate your query into two subqueries:

```
SELECT * from Battles, Player 
WHERE Battles.battle_creator = Player.player_id
ORDER BY Battles.battle_date DESC;
```

...and then:

```
SELECT * from Video 
ORDER BY Battles.battle_date DESC, Player.player_id;
```

The first query will give you one row per battle; the second will give you all videos for all battles, which you can iterate over.

From a scaling perspective, you'll do better to avoid JOINs altogether, so the extra work will be well worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the response nathan - I thought this might be the case but was hoping there was a very simple query to do the job (I have limited mysql knowledge). I will give this a go.

Comment: Cool, glad it was helpful. I hate the "you're doing it wrong" responses to questions, from a scalability perspective, it's better to avoid querying multiple tables altogether. Use simple queries and combine data at the application/service tier FTW. Trying to build a single query to do a complex thing is usually a trap. :)

Comment: Managed to getting working by creating a second query - thanks

Comment: Good call; I had understood it *had* to be one query, but that was only an assumption on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add LIMIT 1 clause to your query to only get first result, or use DISTINCT clause like

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM ...
```

That said, you should not use "SELECT * " when querying for more than one table -
use "SELECT table.*" or "SELECT table.field1, table.field2, ..." to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do "exactly" that, because your query:

```
SELECT * from Battles, Player, Video  ...
```

is implicitly asking for *all the videos*. So you need to ask yourself first, *how do I select that one video I want?*

If you just want one video, whatever, then add `LIMIT 1` to the query and be done with that. `ORDER BY` video_date ASC or DESC before the `LIMIT` to retrieve the earliest or latest video.

Otherwise, you have to do something like:

```
SELECT * from Battles
    JOIN Player ON (Battles.battle_creator = Player.player_id)
    JOIN Video  ON (Battles.battle_id = Video.battle_id 
                    AND Video.player_id = Battles.battle_creator)
WHERE Video.video_id = (SELECT MIN(video_id) FROM Video AS Video2 WHERE
               Battles.battle_id = Video2.battle_id 
               AND Video2.player_id = Battles.battle_creator)
ORDER BY Battles.battle_date DESC;
```

In the example above I used, as "video choice criterion", "the video with smallest video_id". You will want to have an index on (Video.video_id), something like

```
CREATE INDEX video_ndx ON Video(player_id, battle_id, video_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - the second query looks very complicated so I opted to use two simple queries to get the result

Answer (score -1):

As Ninsuo's comment points out, the proper way to control this is, after your ORDER BY clause, specify LIMIT 1.

This won't work if you want the entire table, just without duplicates. Consider running some comparison checks on your returned data, or using SELECT DISTINCT.